# I need to attach an integer to an image in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a python program where I take one initial image *(I will call this `image A`)* and compare several other images *(I will refer to this set of images as `set B`)* to the average color of the initial `image A`.

When I compare an image from `set B` to the initial `image A`, I get an integer value `closeness score`. I would like to somehow attach this score to the image from `set B`. This way I can sort and reference the entire `set B` based on this closeness score.

Here is a more code based explanation:

```
setB = [image1, image2, image3, ..., imageN]

closenessScore(setB)
```

The result of `closenessScore(setB)` gives me an array of values corresponding to `set B`. Example: `[67, 32, 22, ..., 72]`. I need to attach these values to the appropriate image from `set B`, then I need to sort the images in set B based on their closeness score.

I am kind of new to python, so if I need to provide any additional information I would be more than happy to do so.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You just need to initialize [*dict*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), where key will be an image object *(or path)* from `setB` and value will be `closenessScore` of this image. Related: [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/10824407)